# If creating a generic template API that supports returning a variadic list of types, should I use std::tuple or something else?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

So, I have a template API that I want to publish.  This API returns a class type that contains a list of types.

In general, should I use `std::tuple<>` to specify this or should I use something else that may be more lightweight?

I think I've heard that `std::tuple<>` could result in slightly slower compile times, relative to using, say:

```
template <typename...>
struct list {};
```

Is this true?

Comment: *"I think I've heard that std::tuple<> could result in slightly slower compile times. Is this true?"* - we only like to verify rumors that has some empirical numbers...

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Everything using template slows down the compiler by a bit.

Comment: @WhiZTiM, this may have been some time ago.  No idea if it was ever verified.  That is why I'm asking.

Comment: Do slightly slower compilation times actually matter in your case? Sounds like you're worrying about a premature optimisation. What do you mean by "returns a class type"? Are you talking about a function returning an object, or a metafunction "returning" a type? If you mean a metafunction that does `using type = std::tuple<Types...>;` then you won't even instantiate `std::tuple` and so it will be just as fast as your `list` suggestion.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, that is what I am asking about.  A metafunction 'returning' a type.  I was thinking that it shouldn't make a difference, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 4):

> I think I've heard that std::tuple<> could result in slightly slower compile times

This is true. Louis Dionne *(author of Boost.Hana)* mentioned that `std::tuple` was consistently slower than his `hana::tuple` implementation. There is a benchmark involving `std::tuple` on [metaben.ch](http://metaben.ch/#), under "Heterogeneous/`make`".

---

If all you need is a list of types, I suggest simply using:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct type_list { };
```

You cannot do better than that in terms of lightweightness and it  be trivially "converted" to a `std::tuple<Ts...>` or any other variadic template class. Additionally, its semantics and meaning are clearer compared to `std::tuple`, which is often used for run-time computation.

```
template <typename TypeList, template <typename...> class Target>
struct rename;

template <typename... Ts, template <typename...> class Target>
struct rename<type_list<Ts...>, Target>
{
    using type = Target<Ts...>;
};
```

---

If you want an **extremely fast** type-only metaprogramming library, check out [Kvasir.MPL](https://github.com/kvasir-io/mpl).

Comment: So, I should roll my own?  Isn't there some `std` equivalent?

Comment: @Adrian: your call. `std::tuple` isn't likely to ever be a bottleneck, but in my opinion it's misleading if part of the API. You could use `hana` or `kvasir` or roll your own.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you could leave the type undefined in order to prevent accidental construction: `template <typename...> struct type_list;`. Using the type purely as a type (and never as the type of an object) does not require that it be defined, only declared.

Comment: @cdhowie I quite often pass around instances of my tag types (including lists of types) as values.  Infact I'd `template<class...Ts>struct type_list_t{using type=type_list_t;constexpr type_list_t(){}}; template<class...Ts>constexpr type_list_t<Ts...> type_list{};` to make value-style metaprogramming easier to do.